# Loop over a long list at scale with time delay in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently loop a long list with `time.sleep(10)` to a API. The API can take 10 items per query and each query must have a 5 seconds inbetween. Each query will result in a pandas dataframe so I will combine them at the end. I am wondering how to loop over a large list at scale (10 items per time) with a time delay component to a API, or there's a better way to do this.

```
import time
import pandas

long_list ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon', 'mango', 'kiwi']
lista = []

def function_1(abc):
    dat = does_something(abc)
    return dat

for i in long_list:
    lista.append(function_1(i))
    time.sleep(10)

combined_frames = pd.concat(lista).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to take a long list and break it up into sublists of length 10?  The other parts of this seem to be either done or lacking details "`does_something`?".

Comment: If I manage to break it into 10 as a nested list, what's the best way to loop it over with a time delay? The function_1 is just a generic function. @ScottHunter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will call `process` with successive runs of 10 items from `long_list`:

```
cap = 10

for i in range(0,len(long_list),cap):
    process(data[i:i+cap])
```

You already know how to delay between calls.

Comment: So how do I fit the `function_1` in this case? Does `process()` come `from multiprocessing import Process`? Many thanks again!

Comment: `process` is a placeholder for whatever you need to do with these 10-element runs.

Comment: Totally get it now. Thanks!